# Azure / Shared Web App / PHP / PhpManager / output_buffering

Tags: php, azure, output-buffering

As the title describes, I have **a shared Web App in Azure** with PHP 5.4 as well as the Site Extension PhpManager installed (via Kudu). I have used PhpManager to modify the master php.ini file and variable output_buffering to "Off" from the default 4096.

The setting saves (green tick), and remains if you revisit config, but if you view PHP Info (even after restarting the instance), the output_buffering variable is not respected, it still shows 4096, despite the php.ini file config showing "Off"

I've tried appending to both the .user.ini as well as a custom ini path to have a new line;

```
output_buffering = Off
```

This change only results in output_buffering changing to "no value" in PHP Info - but not the desired "Off" result.

Would appreciate any guidance on getting this disabled - I've tried a multitude of ob_flush() flush() ob_start etc to force within the file, with no luck.

As an aside, I created a separate script per below to ensure it wasn't a code issue, and this still outputs in one hit as opposed to progressively as required.

```
<?php
echo 'Starting...<br/>';
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  print "$i<br/>";
  flush();
  sleep(2);
}
print 'DONE!<br/>';
?>
```

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom a handler mapping in `web.config` in your root directory(if you don't have one, just create a new `web.config`). We can leverage `responseBufferLimit="0"` to disable the response buffer in IIS.

Similar with [Use a custom PHP runtime on Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-use-a-custom-php-runtime), but we will use the default installed php cgi execute application and we manually create the configuration.

Please try the following content in your `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
            <add name="PHP-FastCGI"
                path="*.php"
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
                modules="FastCgiModule"
                scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe"
                resourceType="Either"
                requireAccess="Script" 
                responseBufferLimit="0" />
         </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting it to 0:

```
output_buffering = 0
```

From the docs, you can see that this config parameter is expecting a boolean or an integer. When I tested it, I could only get it to behave the way I expected when I used an int.

> **output_buffering boolean/integer**
>
> You can enable output buffering for all files by setting this
>   directive to 'On'. If you wish to limit the size of the buffer to a
>   certain size - you can use a maximum number of bytes instead of 'On',
>   as a value for this directive (e.g., output_buffering=4096). As of PHP
>   4.3.5, this directive is always Off in PHP-CLI.

On the other hand, because the default is 0, I assume that setting it to something invalid and seeing "no value" is the same as setting it to 0. :-)